# Another Firefox relative path conundrum

Tags: html, firefox, path

Ok.
So I know this is probably a stupid question, but I've been traversing SO and Google for the last many hours for an answer and found nothing.

I'm currently creating a HTML5 mobile app using JQM 1.2.0 and Google Maps js V3 - just to set the context.
My problem occurs when I try to test the page in FF 18 desktop version. In every other browser, be it mobile or desktop, I'm not having any problems. Also, I have tried on both localhost as well as the server I'm deploying to, and it's the same result.

In my HTML file I have a relative link to css and js files:

```
<script src="js/general.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css"/>
```

while my links to JQM etc. are absolute as I use a CDN:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

When I use Firebug, I can see that the files with a absolute path are loaded fine, while the relative path links are ignored - or at least I think so, as nothing shows up in neither the Console or the Net pane.

When I check the Html pane in Firebug, it appears as if it has included a  tag pr default (with the correct URL), but not if I try to view page source using the regular FF methods. Even though, I have tried to include a explicit base tag to my header and it changes nothing.

So, to sum up: relative path works fine in all browsers except FF, it it happens on both my server and localhost.

**Update:**
Tried moving the files to the root dir, but it didn't help.
Also, when trying to view the content of the js or css file in Firebug (pressing the arrow to the left of the tag in index.html), it just says:

> Reload the page to get source for: `http://localhost/~u040800/app/general.js`

which, of course does not change after reload.

Comment: Are you sure it's the relative paths?  Have you tried moving the files to the root directory to see if that fixes it?

Comment: hmm..I just tried moving the file to the root dir and it still doesn't work. Which, to be honest, does not help me much.

Comment: It helps you ask a better question.  What is the `Content-type` header reporting for the two files?

Comment: Well, I'm not getting any content type as it seems that FF is ignoring them. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Look at the `Content-type` header in the network inspector of a browser that isn't ignoring them then

Comment: yeah, sorry - long day. It says "application/javascript" for the .js file and "text/css for the .css file

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind - stupid mistake on my side!!

Note to self: when developing, do make sure that your add-ons are disabled before asking SO! otherwise, you make a complete ass of yourself!!

Yes, it is correct - I forgot to disable Ad-Blocker...

@robertc: Sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: Good to see people being honest about their mistakes :)